# How to capture view content in symfony for pdf output

Tags: php, pdf, symfony1

I'm using Symfony and mPDF.

I'm trying to integrate both but am running into some problems.

I need to capture the content of a view but can't see how to do it.

```
  public function executePDF(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->object = $this->getRoute()->getObject();

    require_once 'mpdf.php';

    /* Example code from mPDF site */
    $mpdf=new mPDF('win-1252','A4','','',20,15,48,25,10,10);
    $mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true; // false is default
    $mpdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
    $mpdf->SetTitle("Acme Trading Co. - Invoice");
    $mpdf->SetAuthor("Acme Trading Co.");
    $mpdf->SetWatermarkText("Paid");
    $mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
    $mpdf->watermark_font = 'DejaVuSansCondensed';
    $mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.1;
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

    $this->setLayout(false);
    $html = $this->getResponse()->getContent();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
  }
```

With the above example, `$html` is returned as an empty string. I have a view template relating to this action (PDFSuccess.php) which accesses the `$object` and has the HTML that mPDF will use.

Thanks for any help.

As it is just now, when accessing this action it does open a PDF correctly, but there is no content in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't done this in this specific context but you could try:

```
$html = $this->getPartial('moduleName/partialName');
```

... where the template is a partial (_partialName) inside a given module. As it's a partial, there's no need to switch off the layout.

You can also pass variables to it:

```
$html = $this->getPartial('moduleName/partialName', array('var' => 'something'));
```

...

If that doesn't work, here's a question relating to email templates that contains an alternative way of doing this (see the accepted answer):

[Email body in Symfony 1.4 mailer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255109/email-body-in-symfony-1-4-mailer)