# Symfony 1.4 email view

Tags: php, email, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer

I'm using symfony 1.4. For email, I'm using SwiftMail. Following code is working perfectly fine for me.

```
class ForgetPasswordMessage extends Swift_Message
{
    const SUBJECT = 'Reset Password verification mail from Awssum.com.';
    const MESSAGE = 'Test Message';
    public function __construct($to)
    {
        parent::__construct(self::SUBJECT, self::MESSAGE);

        $this->setFrom(array(Member::getAdminMember()->getEmail() => Troupa));
        $this->setTo($to);
        $this->setContentType('text/html');
    }
}//ForgetPasswordMessage
```

However I need to send a HTML mail. I can update `MESSAGE` to write html tags but I guess it is not a right approach. HTML must go in templates. I try [solution on other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255109/email-body-in-symfony-1-4-mailer) but its not working for me (Failing in sfView). Again that question answer condition without using mail classes.

How can write and use views for Email classes?

**Edit after comment 1**

Code in controller

```
public function executeForgetMail(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    try
    {
        $to = $request->getParameter('email');
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->add(AppUsersPeer::EMAIL, $to);
        $user = AppUsersPeer::doSelectOne($criteria);
        if($user)
        {
            $mailer=$this->getMailer();
            $mailer->send(new ForgetPasswordMessage($to));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("The email does not exist. Please try again.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', sprintf($e->getMessage()));
        $this->redirect('signup/forgot');
    }
    $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', "An email with password reset link has been send to your email.");
    $this->redirect('signup/forgot');
}
```

**Edit after answer's comment**

New code in `ForgetPasswordMail.class.php`

```
<?php
class ForgetPasswordMail extends TroupaBaseMessage
{
    public function __construct($user) {
        $subject = 'Reset Password verification mail from Awssum.com.';

        sfLoader::loadHelpers(array('Partial'));

        $mailContext = array('user' => $user);
        $mailBody = get_partial('global/emails/forget_password', $mailContext);

        parent::__construct($user->getEmail(), $mailBody);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call your class `ForgetPasswordMessage` and with which parameters ? Can you post the snippet on how you send a mail? (from an action I guess)

Comment: Hi @j0k I edited the question with action class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the parameters from `ForgetPasswordMessage` to accept the html content:

```
class ForgetPasswordMessage extends Swift_Message
{
    const SUBJECT = 'Reset Password verification mail from Awssum.com.';
    const MESSAGE = 'Test Message';

    public function __construct($to, $htmlBody = null)
    {
        $message = self::MESSAGE;
        if (null !== $htmlBody)
        {
          $message = $htmlBody;
        }

        parent::__construct(self::SUBJECT, $message);

        $this->setFrom(array(Member::getAdminMember()->getEmail() => Troupa));
        $this->setTo($to);
        $this->setContentType('text/html');
    }
}
```

and then call a partial to have the html content:

```
    $to = $request->getParameter('email');
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->add(AppUsersPeer::EMAIL, $to);
    $user = AppUsersPeer::doSelectOne($criteria);
    if($user)
    {
        $mailBody = $this->getPartial('module/partial_name', array('user' => $user));
        $mailer=$this->getMailer();
        $mailer->send(new ForgetPasswordMessage($to, $mailBody));
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("The email does not exist. Please try again.");
    }
```

Check [this cookbook](http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/email#chapter_ea251c4e9e2f8c2a0fda95adab0cc06d_render_an_e_mail) (for sf 1.2 but ok for 1.4)

**Edit**

Otherwise, you could call the partial directly from your class:

```
class ForgetPasswordMessage extends Swift_Message
{
    const SUBJECT = 'Reset Password verification mail from Awssum.com.';
    const MESSAGE = 'Test Message';

    public function __construct($to)
    {
        // needed to be able to user `get_partial`
        sfApplicationConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers(array('Partial'));

        $mailContext = array('test' => 'wahou');
        $mailBody = get_partial('module/partial_name', $mailContext);

        parent::__construct(self::SUBJECT, $mailBody);

        $this->setFrom(array(Member::getAdminMember()->getEmail() => Troupa));
        $this->setTo($to);
        $this->setContentType('text/html');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks J0k, that worked but ideally speaking, this is not the way I expected. If controller(action class) is selecting the partial, what is the purpose of using specialized email class `ForgetPasswordMessage`? I guess EMail classes should decide the view, if not, using `$this->getMailer()->composeAndSend($sender, $recipient, $subject, $body);` in action class should be more preferred way. Its just my view but can you suggest if there is any benefit of making separate email classes.

Comment: @KapilSharma right, it remember me an other way I implement in an other project, I'll update my answer

Comment: Great J0k. I was not aware about `sfLoader::loadHelpers` till now, and that is what I was exactly looking for. You had lot of experience in Symfony. An Off the topic question, did you learn about all these functions with 1. `slowly with long experience`, 2. `examine symfony code` or 3. `some documentations available for that`. After Jobeet, I'm learning symfony on SO, not from symfony documentation :)

Comment: Well [the cookbook](http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/) has some interesting implementation. [The More with symfony book](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/) is also interesting. But I really learn in a long experience building various website (intranet, ecommerce, custom apps, etc ..). But your 3 points are basically the main source in this order 1, 3 and 2. You code, you're blocked, you look at the doc and then into the code :)

Comment: J0k, I got `Class 'sfLoader' not found in D:\projects\troupasvn\trunk\apps\frontend\lib\email\ForgetPasswordMail.class.php on line 7`. Should I load anything else before `sfLoader::loadHelpers`?